# Elasticsearch 5.6: [nested] nested object under path [xxxxxx] is not of nested type

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to upgrade to elasticsearch 5.6 and I am getting the following error when doing a request. It works fine in an earlier version we have been running for years. Any ideas?

> {"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"[nested] nested object
>   under path [categories] is not of nested type"}

Here is my mapping:

```
    .Mappings(mappings => mappings
        .Map<ESProduct>(product => product
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(prop1 => prop1
                .Nested<ESCategory>(n => n
                    .Name("categories")
                    .AutoMap()
                    .Properties(props => props
                        .Keyword(s => s.Name(p => p.Id).Index())
                        .Keyword(s => s.Name(p => p.Name).Index())
                        .Text(s => s.Name(p => p.Path)
                            .Analyzer("path_analyzer")
                            .Index()
                        )
                        .Text(s => s.Name(p => p.IdNamePath)
                            .Fielddata(true)
                            .Analyzer("path_analyzer")
                            .Index()
                        )
                    )
                )
```

My request is something like this:

```
{
    "aggs":{
        "agg_manufacturers":{
            "terms":{
                "field":"manufacturer.idName",
                "size":10000
            }
        },
       "cat_nest":{
           "aggs":{
               "agg_categories":{
                   "terms":{
                       "field":"categories.idNamePath",
                       "include":"/10000.*",
                       "size":10000
                   }
               }
           },
           "nested":{
               "path":"categories"
           }
       }
   },
   "query":{
       "bool":{
           "must":[
               {
                   "nested":{
                       "path":"categories",
                       "query":{
                           "term":{
                               "categories.path":{
                                   "value":"10000/13168"
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               },
               {
                   "bool":{
                       "should":[
                           {
                               "term":{}
                           }
                       ]
                   }
               },
               {
                   "term":{}
               }
           ]
       }
   },
   "size":0
}
```

My mapping:

```
{
  "my-index": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "properties": {
          "categories": {
            "properties": {
              "autoKeywords": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "displayOrder": { "type": "long" },
              "id": { "type": "long" },
              "idName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "idNamePath": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "isFeatured": { "type": "boolean" },
              "manualSort": { "type": "boolean" },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "namePath": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "parentID": { "type": "long" },
              "path": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "showProduct": { "type": "boolean" },
              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "manufacturer": {
            "properties": {
              "displayOrder": { "type": "long" },
              "id": { "type": "long" },
              "idName": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "imageUrl": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "isFeatured": { "type": "boolean" },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Debug Info:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on PUT: /my-index
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: https://domain.../ Took: 00:00:00.6376279
# ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: illegal_argument_exception Reason: "mapper [title] cannot be changed from type [text] to [keyword]"
# OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData)
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
# Response:
<Response stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>
```

Comment: Could you share index mapping?

Comment: I just edited to show the mapping. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: and which version do you use?

Comment: 5.6 hosted on Amazon

Comment: sorry, meant to ask, which version of NEST do you use :)

Comment: I also get this error, when I AM using keyword for manufacturer.idName..... Set fielddata=true on [manufacturer.idName] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field

Comment: Nest version is 5.6.6

Comment: Could you also share a debug information from `.CreateIndex(..)` response?

Comment: OK, I see an error (added above). I didn't even think to look there because the index seemed to be created successfully.

Comment: Could this be the root of my problem? "Fields need to be consistent across types. For instance if two fields have the same name in different types of the same index, they need to be of the same field type (string, date, etc.) and have the same configuration."

Comment: Are you trying to update existing index or creat brand new?

Comment: yes, this is the problem.

Comment: I am deleting the index and creating new. I fixed some of the errors. By looking at the debuginformation I can work through the problems now. Thanks!!!!!